# Can someone help identify these two groundcover plants?

Tags: identification, flowers, ground-cover

I am trying to identify the purple flowers (and the groundcover plant that they grow from.) The light green leaves on the left of the photo are NOT the same plant. Those leaves are the same as the plant in photo #2

[image]

This plant has slightly bumpy leaves, but not jagged edges. It has five petaled white flowers too.

[image]

I am doing an ecology project for biology and we have to identify these plants (genus and species) I haven't found the right species yet, so I appreciate all your help.

Comment: In what location and what type of growing area (open field, woodland??) are they growing?

Comment: They are a landscaping groundcover plant, human planted at my high school. This is in California, USA. I'm pretty sure this is evergreen. At first we thought the white flowered plant was this: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Group_of_Galium_odoratum_in_forest.jpg but the petal # and leaf texture/arrangement doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Ceanothus prostratus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceanothus_prostratus)*, possibly, for the first, blue flowered one? Can't tell how tall or wide it is, you haven't said whether its evergreen, and no idea what part of the world you're in, so difficult to make a proper ID, but that's what it reminds me of. No idea on the white flowered one.

Comment: We guessed ceanothus hearstiorum for the blue flowers but your suggestion matches better. We were in the ballpark at least! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the white flower in the second picture is some species of [*Myoporum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoporum).

Comment: Why the downvote? This appears to be a useful answer.

Comment: From the link Myoporum are native to Australia/Pacific.  With 32 species this could be right but we need a species to be sure. (and no, I did not down vote)

Comment: @kevinsky: Looks a whole lot like *M. parvifolium*, which was noted as being sold in California (where the above plant was found) [here](http://cisr.ucr.edu/myoporum_thrips.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the white flowered one is an evergreen Euphorbia of some type.